# byobu: Can I launch commands in windows when byobu starts

Tags: byobu

Byobu seems very simple and easy to use compared to others I have tried. I would like to start Byobu and have my commands launched in the correct window. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Byobu):

> Users can create a list of windows to launch at startup in
>   $DATA/windows. This file is the same syntax as ~/.screenrc, each line
>   specifying a window using the "screen" command, as described in
>   Screen's manual.

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to be able to predefine a set of byobu windows and have commands launched in them.  I am using tmux under byobu.  That documentation seems to be referring to screen, not tmux.  I also don't see the connection between byobu layout and launching commands in those windows.